# Не могу сложить два поля при заполнении таблицы

Tags: mysql

Дано: таблица отрезков с такой структурой:

```
CREATE TABLE `14p_80_80` (
  `chr` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `left` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `right` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  UNIQUE KEY `chr_left_right` (`chr`,`left`,`right`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4061631 DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 COMMENT='Параметры картирования 80-80';
```

Где **chr** - ось n-мерного измерения, **left** и **right** - координаты концов отрезков на оси, **count** - число отрезков.

Хочу получить уже таблицу точек по схеме: вначале в таблицу вносятся все левые концы отрезков (если координаты концов совпадают, то их число суммируется), затем - правые (также с суммированием в случае совпадения координат). Вот SQL-query:

```
CREATE TABLE `14p_80_80_pos` (
`chr` int(11) NOT NULL,
`pos` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`count` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `chr_pos` (`chr`, `pos`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

INSERT INTO `14p_80_80_pos` (`chr`, `pos`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `left` as `pos`, `count` cnt
FROM `14p_80_80`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`count` = `count` + cnt;

INSERT INTO `14p_80_80_pos` (`chr`, `pos`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `right` as `pos`, `count` cnt
FROM `14p_80_80`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`count` = `count` + cnt;
```

Вылетает ошибка "Error Code: 1052. Column 'count' in field list is ambiguous". Не могу понять почему, подобный подход на других таблицах работал.

Comment: перед `count`, особенно в правой части update расставьте имена таблиц. SQL не может понять какой из них имеется ввиду

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не разобрался, как вставлять код в комментарии, отвечу здесь:

Подобный код после расставления имён таблиц, благодаря комментарию Mike выше, отработал:

```
INSERT INTO `14p_80_80_pos` (`chr`, `pos`, `count`)
SELECT `chr`, `left` pos, `count` FROM `14p_80_80` order by `chr`,`left` limit 0,200
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`14p_80_80_pos`.`count` = `14p_80_80_pos`.`count` + `14p_80_80`.count ;
```

Меня смущало опасение, что будет произведено лишнее сложение.

Comment: `не разобрался, как вставлять код в комментарии` - комментарии и не предназначены для этого. Они нужны для уточнений. Всё. Остальное должно быть либо в вопросе - весь код, пояснения, либо в ответе - решение..