# Сложный SQL-запрос, можно ли обойтись без создания временной таблицы?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, биоинформатика

Есть таблица данных секвенирования, все поля описывать не буду, только нужные:

```
table newdata
chr = varchar(16) // название хромосомы
left = bigint // левая координата паттерна в геноме
right = bigint // правая координата паттерна в геноме 
count = int // число условно-одинаковых паттернов
```

и таблица генов, тоже все поля не буду описывать, только нужные, поля означают то же самое - координаты генов в геноме:

```
table g38_genes
id = bigint // уникальный идентификатор гена 
chr = varchar(16)
left = bigint // левая координата гена в геноме
right = bigint // правая координата гена в геноме 
priority = int // показатель приоритетности
```

Задача состоит из двух частей: вначале нужно найти все концы отрезков из таблицы `newdata`, число которых превышает N, то есть если `left` одного отрезка совпадает с `left` другого или `right` третьего, нужно все значения `count` сложить и представить в виде одной координаты, допустим, `pos`. Решение я подсмотрел у коллеги в его топике [Не могу сложить два поля при заполнении таблицы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/745870/), но делаю немного по-другому, создавая временную таблицу (N будет учитываться на следующем шаге):

```
CREATE temporary table `temp_pos` 
(`chr` varchar(16) NOT NULL, 
`pos` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`count` int(11) NOT NULL, 
UNIQUE KEY `chr_pos` (`chr`, `pos`) );
INSERT INTO `temp_pos` (`chr`, `pos`, `count`) 
SELECT `chr`, `left` pos, `count` FROM `newdata` 
where `chr`=1 order by `left` limit 0,200 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`temp_pos`.`count` = `temp_pos`.`count` + `newdata`.count ;
INSERT INTO `temp_pos` (`chr`, `pos`, `count`) 
SELECT `chr`, `right` pos, `count` FROM `newdata` 
where `chr`=1 order by `right` limit 0,200 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`temp_pos`.`count` = `temp_pos`.`count` + `newdata`.count ;
```

Временную таблицу я создаю потому, что промежуточный результат мне не нужен. Мне нужен результат второго шага. В нём я должен найти все значения pos, которые попадают на гены, т.е. `g38_genes.left < pos < g38_genes.right`. Я это делаю так (N=9):

```
select A.*, B.`id`, B.`left`, B.`right` 
from `temp_pos` A, `g38_genes` B  
where A.`count` > 9 and A.`chr`=1 and B.`chr` = 1 and B.`priority` > 4
and A.`pos` < B.`right` and A.`pos` > B.`left` 
order by A.`pos`;
```

Фактически, задача в целом состоит в том, чтобы найти координаты концов всех паттернов, которые попадают в тело важных для рассмотрения генов (priority > 4) , чтобы количество этих концов паттернов было достаточно большим (count > 9). Дальше я планировал менять увеличивать limit (201, 400; 401,600 и т.д.), чтобы обойти всю таблицу newdata.

Код работает. Но неправильно из-за limit 0,200 - не все паттерны учитываются. Я могу, конечно, создать не временную, а постоянную таблицу для хранения данных концов отрезков и работать уже с ней. Но не хотелось бы. Отсюда вопросы:

1. Могу ли я создать огромную временную таблицу? Т.е. убрать `limit` и дождаться, пока обработается вся первая хромосома (`chr=1`), а затем уже с ней работать?
2. Или (что для меня было бы лучше) так переделать код так, чтобы вообще не использовать временную таблицу? Ломал голову, получались дикие конструкции, которые не работали :(

Comment: А сколько у вас записей в таблицах newdata (с chr=1)и g38_genes (c chr=1 и priority>4) ? Если во второй гораздо меньше, чем в первой, возможно более быстрым путем будет сначала найти пересечения, а потом посчитать количества

Comment: @Mike По-разному. Бывает и так, и так. В случае генов - да, во второй таблице значительно меньше, а в случае повторов или другого паттерна - примерно одинаковое количество записей.

Comment: А пересечений вот по тем условиям больше-меньше много, почти все записи или может гораздо меньше исходных объемов. или те условия вообще размножают записи, т.е. одна запись первой выборки пересекается с многими из другой таблицы

Comment: @Mike пересечения по первому условию (когда left, right объединяются) уменьшают количество записей примерно в 10-12 раз. По второму - пока не знаю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Задача состоит из двух частей: вначале нужно найти все концы отрезков из таблицы `newdata`, число которых превышает `N`, то есть если `left` одного отрезка совпадает с `left` другого или `right` третьего, нужно все значения `count` сложить и представить в виде одной координаты, допустим, `pos`.

```
SELECT `chr`, `pos`, SUM(`count`) `count`
FROM 
(
  SELECT `chr`, `left` `pos`, SUM(`count`) `count`
  FROM newdata
  -- WHERE `chr`=1
  GROUP BY `chr`, `left`
UNION ALL
  SELECT `chr`, `right` `pos`, SUM(`count`) `count`
  FROM newdata
  -- WHERE `chr`=1
  GROUP BY `chr`, `right`
)
GROUP BY `chr`, `pos`
```

Формально группировки в подзапросе лишние - но (особенно при наличии правильного индекса) они значительно ускорят выполнение всего запроса.

> Временную таблицу я создаю потому, что промежуточный результат мне не нужен. Мне нужен результат второго шага. В нём я должен найти все значения `pos`, которые попадают на гены, т.е. `g38_genes.left` < `pos` < `g38_genes.right`.

```
SELECT A.*, B.`id`, B.`left`, B.`right` 
FROM (
      SELECT `chr`, `pos`, SUM(`count`) `count`
      FROM 
      (
        SELECT `chr`, `left` `pos`, SUM(`count`) `count`
        FROM newdata
        -- WHERE `chr`=1
        GROUP BY `chr`, `left`
      UNION ALL
        SELECT `chr`, `right` `pos`, SUM(`count`) `count`
        FROM newdata
        -- WHERE `chr`=1
        GROUP BY `chr`, `right`
      )
      GROUP BY `chr`, `pos`
    ) A, `g38_genes` B  
WHERE A.`count` > 9 
--  AND A.`chr` = 1 
  AND B.`chr` = 1 
  AND B.`priority` > 4
  AND A.`pos` < B.`right` 
  AND A.`pos` > B.`left` 
ORDER BY A.`pos`;
```

Вроде так...

PS. И не надо делать отбор по `` `chr`=1 `` во всех местах - если выполнить отбор в подзапросе, то условие `` A.`chr` = 1 `` теряет смысл.

Comment: Спасибо, пойду проверять. По поводу chr=1 - грамотное замечание, но оно возникло не от хорошей жизни. В идеале, теперь можно подумать и заменить его на условие A.chr = B.chr, тогда выборка будет проходить для всех хромосом

Comment: Правильный индекс - это добавление в таблицу паттернов  UNIQUE KEY `chr_left_right` (`chr`, `left`, `right` ) ?

Comment: Ругнулась "Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias", но добавил алиас C  для внутреннего SELECT (перед GROUP BY `chr`, `pos`) и запрос пошёл. Для самой маленькой неполовой 22й хромосомы длился минут 5 (mysql workbench подставил свое стандартное LIMIT 0,1000), но это здорово! Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: Для каждого из подзапросов нужен свой индекс - для первого `chr_left(chr, left)`, для второго соответственно `chr_right(chr, right )`. И у меня есть весьма определённые сомнения в том, что они должны быть уникальны...

Comment: *добавил алиас C для внутреннего SELECT (перед GROUP BY chr, pos)* Не поленитесь ещё добавить алиас этой таблицы для всех полей из неё... хуже не будет, а порядка добавится.

Comment: Вот только, если я правильно понимаю идею этого запроса, не учтен следующий фактор: нужно обязательно исключить случаи, когда POS, удачно попавший в середину одного из генов в g38_genes, попадает на LEFT или RIGHT другого гена в g38_genes. Но как это сделать, кроме последующей проверки, представить не могу.

Comment: Для учёта подобной "неприятности" надо добавить в источник данных запроса ещё одну копию таблицы g38_genes и связать её левым джойном по условию вхождения и неравенству ид гена, а в условиях отбора поставить WHERE g38_genes_2.id IS NULL.

Comment: @ViktorTomilov да, вы правы, мне как-то казалось, что это автоматически учтено. Akina, еще раз спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @Akina Так как вы подсказали, у меня не получилось реализовать :( Попробовал по-другому, через NOT IN: вот запрос https://pastebin.com/FFH3Ehkz  Поругаете или похвалите? :) 48 секунд всего выполняется